# Conditional Probability about Bayesian Network

Tags: proof-writing, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

[image: e]

Given the above Bayesian Network ($A,B,C,D$ are events), how can I prove the following equality?

$$
\begin{align}
P(D|A) &= P(D|B \cap C)P(B|A)P(C|A)+ \\
       &\ \ \ \ \ \ P(D|B \cap C^c)P(B|A)P(C^c|A)+ \\  
       &\ \ \ \ \ \ P(D|B^c \cap C)P(B^c|A)P(C|A)+ \\
       &\ \ \ \ \ \ P(D|B^c \cap C^c)P(B^c|A)P(C^c|A)     
\end{align}
$$

---

(Add)
I have no idea about using $$\def\P{\mathop{\sf P}}\P(A,B,C,D)=\P(D\mid B,C)\P(B\mid A)\P(C\mid A)\P(A)$$

I can't progress over this:

$$P(D|A) = \frac{P(D \cap A)}{P(A)}$$
$$
\begin{align}
P(D \cap A) &= P(B \cap C)P(D \cap A|B,C) +\\
            & P(B \cap C^c)P(D \cap A|B,C^c) +\\
            & P(B^c \cap C)P(D \cap A|B^c,C) +\\
            & P(B^c \cap C^c)P(D \cap A|B^c,C^c) \\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I prove following equality?

The Factorisation encoded by that DAG is: $$\def\P{\mathop{\sf P}}\P(A,B,C,D)=\P(D\mid B,C)\P(B\mid A)\P(C\mid A)\P(A)$$

And likewise for the terms involving complements.

Begin with this.

Also use the *Law of Total Probability* and the *Definition for Conditional Probability*.

Comment: I have add more question @Graham Kemp

Comment: Try the Law of Total Probability: $\mathsf P(A,D)={\mathsf P(A,B,C,D)+\mathsf P(A,B,C^{\small\complement},D)+\mathsf P(A,B^{\small\complement},C,D)+\mathsf P(A,B^{\small\complement},C^{\small\complement},D)}$, @firia2000 .